# .replace() index use as variable for a loop

Tags: python, replace

**hi everyone!**
I am a beginner and I can't find answer for this:

```
one = [" January ", " February ", " March ", " April ", " May ", \
        " June ", " July ", " August ", " September ", " October ", \
        " November ", " December ", "   ", "IPS", "COL", "BRT"]

two = ["/01/", "/02/", "/03/", "/04/", "/05/", "/06/", "/07/", "/08/",\
        "/09/", "/10/", "/11/", "/12/", ",", "", "", ""]

a = len(one)     
b = len(two)

while a>0:
    text = open("database.txt", "r")
    text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace(one[a], two[a])
    x = open("new_database.txt","w")
    x.writelines(text)
    x.close()
    a = a - 1
```

**the error is:**

```
    text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace(one[a], two[a])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

*if anyone can help, much appreciated!*

Comment: If `a` is the length of `one` then `a` is out of range for `one`, and `one[a]` will cause an index error. Indexes for a list of length `a` must be strictly less than `a`.

Comment: List indexes go from 0 to `len-1`. So you need to do `a = len(one)-1`

Comment: in addition to *Khelwood*, python is indexing lists from 0. That means, that you also should do `while a >= 0`

Comment: Or you could use `for a in range(len(one)-1, -1, -1):`

Comment: Every time through the loop you do your replacement on the original `database.txt`, not the result of the previous replacement.

Comment: After you use `join()`, `text` is a string, not a list. Use `write()`, not `writelines()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because list indexes are zero-based, so the valid indexes of `one` are `0` through `len(one)-1`. Since you initiaze `a` to `len(one)`, it's outside the range.

But instead of manually assigning index variables and decrementing them, you should just loop through the list elements. You can use `zip()` to loop through two lists in parallel.

Here's a better way to write it:

```
with open("database.txt", "r") as indb, open("new_database.txt", "w") as outdb:
    for line in indb:
        for old, new in zip(one, two):
            line = line.replace(old, new)
        outdb.write(line)
```

Comment: oh wow! I'm very new to programming, but ..baby-steps. Thanks!